# Session stays active after logout in Oracle Apex 20.1, 20.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I've noticed that after clicking logout in Oracle Apex 20+ apps sessions stays alive.
It wasn't a problem untill I've migrated app from Apex 4.2. In this version after logout there is no longer session with specific user_name.
In both &LOGOUT_URL. is the same:

```
/apex_authentication.logout?p_app_id=XXX&p_session_id=XXX
```

Anything changed in recent version of APEX how logout works?
There is a need to always close sessions after logging out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions will remain in active in the apex_workspace_sessions until the session timeout(**Maximum Session Idle Time in Seconds/Maximum Session Length in Seconds**) mentioned in the application exceeds.

If you are on 18.1 or higher you can use apex_session.delete_session to do all the work for you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'You must close the session...". How to do it?

Comment: Are you sure? You checked apex_workspace_sessions after clicking logout with &LOGOUT_URL. ? I'm pretty sure it won't work. I described this situation in question and it does not closing the session. I created a postlogout procedure with APEX_SESSION.DELETE_SESSION and this finnaly closing the apex sessions.

Comment: I think my answer confused you. I have edited my answer for better understanding. Please verify the answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Previous answer was just describing what i wrote in question :) like I wrote I already wrote that i used APEX_SESSION.DELETE_SESSION as postlogout procedure and it works fine. Thank you for hint that it's all becouse session timeout settings.